# Is the previous state of Ethereum saved to level db file after a state change has occurred

Tags: blockchain, state

Newbie here please I am a bit confused. when a state change occurs is the previous state trie updated or it is saved to level db and a new state trie is generated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the client implementation. For example geth for optimization purposes keeps recent changes in memory and only flushes the state after a timeout or some changes threshold is reached.